# Load different template for module on homepage

Tags: magento-2.1, module, layout, theme, page-layouts

I can't make my homepage to load a different template for my module.

I created a theme based on Magento/blank and created a module that changes navigation menu to nice looking vertical mega-menu and they all work just fine.

But I want to make my module to look different on the homepage. So I created one more template file: **module-homepage.phtml**

So now there are two template files in my 
app/code/frontend/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates folder

1. module.phtml
2. module-homepage.phtml

Then I created **custom-homepage.xml** file and put it here:
app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme_name/page_layout/
with the following content:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
        <page layout="2columns-left" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

            <head>
                <!-- Add local resources -->
                <css src="css/whateverstyle.css"/>
            </head>
            <body>
                <referenceBlock name="block.name" template="Vendor_Module::module-homepage.phtml" />
            </body>
        </page>
```

I applied it and it did not work. Homepage loaded blank. Because it was page_configuration and NOT page_layout XML file.

Then I changed its contents to the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="2columns-left"/>
    <referenceContainer name="page.top">

        <referenceBlock name="block.name" template="Vendor_Module::module-homepage.phtml"/>

    </referenceContainer>
</layout>
```

Still no result. Homepage loads fine now, but with no changes. My module-homepage.phtml is probably being ignored.

**system.log** gives me these 5 lines:

```
[2017-06-21 12:40:40] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_4c7461af04bb11fe209659d7147d2c579 and handles default, cms_index_index, cms_page_view, cms_index_index_id_home: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []

[2017-06-21 12:40:40] main.INFO: Cyclic dependency in merged layout for handle: 2columns-left [] []

[2017-06-21 12:40:40] main.INFO: Cyclic dependency in merged layout for handle: 2columns-left [] []

[2017-06-21 12:40:40] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_4cdabc34b90cd18ffdcfe81ef0f5a7189 and handles custom-homepage: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []

[2017-06-21 12:40:40] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_46f1b068ec7ccf4878f9284dd1137afd1 and handles catalog_product_prices: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []
```

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED.
It turned out that you must upload your custom layout in DESIGN in admin area, and not the xml files in template.

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEM SOLVED.
It turned out that you must upload your custom layout in DESIGN in admin area, and not the xml files in template.